# How I can pay amount in decimal on stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am developing a website using django. I need to integrate Stripe payment gateway into my website. I implemented the payment process successfully, but I am getting "Invalid Parameters" error if charge amount in decimal.

Comment: I found solution just enter 10050 only if want to pay 100.50, no need to put .0

Comment: Stripe always consider payment in cents that means if you need to charge 1$ you need to enter 100 cents so the issue of decimals are been easily handled.

Answer (score 1):

Due to potential issues with floating point math, Stripe only accepts an integer for payment amounts. For currencies with decimal amounts, Stripe's API takes the smallest division; for example, in USD, the payment amount is denominated in cents, not dollars; for $1.00, you'd send `100`.